# Coding templates - auto property at top of code file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

It might seem like a small problem, but I was wondering if there is any support from either Visual Studio or a 3rd party application to configure where Visual Studio places certain auto-generated code.

When I am programming, I try to be as efficient as possible, and use 'Ctrl+.' a lot to automatically implement interfaces, fields, properties etc.. and one of the issues i have is that EVERY time I want to create a property in a class file (by typing in the usage first, then Ctrl+. the red invalid text, choosing `Generate Property Stub` when prompted) is Visual Studio places the code at the very bottom of the class file.

This is not how I structure my code files, and for better or worse I would much prefer it if the Auto-Properties were generated at the top.

So instead of (as would happen on auto-generation)

```
public class ObjectProvider
{
    public ObjectProvider(Object o)
    {
        this.Object = o;
    }

    public object Object { get; private set; }
}
```

I would prefer

```
public class ObjectProvider
{
    public object Object { get; private set; }

    public ObjectProvider(Object o)
    {
        this.Object = o;
    }
}
```

A small change I know, but when I am coding (at the least!) 5 days a week, for about 40 hours - I think this would actually save me a lot of time!

Answer (score 1):

At the company I work for, nearly all developers use ReSharper. Once you've learned some keyboard shortcuts, you can *really* improve your efficiency.

For example, the shortcut to cleanup a code file (Ctrl+E, C). Beside other cleanup actions, it reorders all members in a class (which might be what you want).

http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/

Comment: I do actually have re-sharper, and its a great tool. I haven't however been able to find anything related to the positions of auto-properties?

Comment: Well, I don't think ReSharper distinguishes between auto-properties and "custom" properties. But at least it arranges all fields, properties and methods and groups them together. Unfortunately you can't specify any options regarding the position of the members while reordering them (or at least I haven't found this option yet).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [default `prop` snippet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z41h7fat%28VS.90%29.aspx), which will format a property in place of your caret and allows for easy editing. Type "`prop`" then hit Tab twice to get this:

```
public int MyProperty { get; set; }
```

`int` will already be highlighted so just key in the name of the type, hit Tab twice then key in the name of the property. This all happens from the current position of the caret.

Comment: I could - but I like the style of starting to write the usage first. So in the example I gave, i would write 'this.Object = o', then Ctrl+. over the 'Object' to create the auto-property. A default snippet would unfortunately break this style, as I would still have to spend the time hooking up the values in the constructor, or where ever I wanted to place the initial variable assignment.